# How to change order in multidimentional array when sort one subarray in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I sort one subarray how can I change the order of other subarray's elements according to the new order of sorted subarray:

```js
var op = [];

op[0] = [0, "1:7001", "1:7002", "1:7003", "1:7004", "1:7005"];
op[1] = [1, "1:8001", "1:8002", "1:8003", "1:8004", "1:7005"];
op[2] = ["asw", 3, 5, 1, 10, 2];


op[2] = op[2].slice(0, 1).concat(op[2].slice(1, op[2].length).sort(function(a,b) {
    return b - a;
}));

console.log(op);
```

The expected array should look like:

```
[0, "1:7004", "1:7002", "1:7001", "1:7005", "1:7003"];
[1, "1:8004", "1:8002", "1:8001", "1:7005", "1:8003"];
[ "asw", 10, 5, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a temporary array with objects of value and index for sorting and map the other arrays with the indices of the sorted array.

This approach is called [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

```js
var op = [
        [0, "1:7001", "1:7002", "1:7003", "1:7004", "1:7005"],
        [1, "1:8001", "1:8002", "1:8003", "1:8004", "1:7005"],
        ["asw", 3, 5, 1, 10, 2]
    ],
    order = op[2]                                  // take op[2] as pattern
        .slice(1)                                  // omit first element
        .map((v, i) => ({ v, i: i + 1 }))          // take value and index with offset
        .sort(({ v: a }, { v: b }) => b - a);      // sort by value desc

order.unshift({ i: 0 });                           // keep first item at index zero

op = op.map(a => order.map(({ i }) => a[i]));      // map value at index

console.log(op);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what do you mean with *subarrays*? how do they look like?